Position of a square inside a circle
Suppose you have a circle with a square as shown in the figure below with $P_1$ and $P_2$ being points on the radius of the circle and $C_1$ to $C_4$ being the corners of the rotated square. The radius of the circle and size of square are known but the rotation angle of the square is unknown.
If you could measure the distances:

from $P_1$ to each of the corners of the square
from $P_2$ to each of the corners of the square
from $P_1$ to $P_2$.

Is it possible to recover the vertical and horizontal translation from the center of the circle to the center of the square? Or do you need more information? Assuming this information constrains the problem sufficiently, how would you solve for vertical and horizontal translation from the center of the circle to the center of the square?


Are any coordinates known?

Only distances and sizes

You can solve for the distance between the circle and square centres. Assume P1 = (0, 1) and P2 = (0, -1) for example. Then each vertex of the square can be in two possible positions. Now use the side length of the square and scale it to the transformed diagram to find say, points C1 and C3 and hence the centre of the square will be their midpoint. The centre of the circle is just an application of Pythagoras, since it must lie on the x-axis.

If you just know the distances, then the answer is no. Take your figure and rotate everything by an arbitrary angle around the circle center. All the distances remain the same, but the vertical and horizontal position of the square change.
Also, suppose that you know $P_1$ and $P_2$ and the distances to each corner. Draw the $P_1P_2$ line. Now draw the mirror image of the square with respect to this line. The distances are the same, but the position is usually different (unless the mirror transformation is a symmetry operation for the square).

In case this is not clear to the OP from this answer: If we fix $P_1P_2$ on the circle, we can construct everything else (square, circle center, square center). But there is a mirrored construction on the other side of $P_1P_2$ as well.

As noticed, and more in general, if we do not refer any position to an external frame of reference then it is not possible recovery any absolute position only knowing relative distances since any rigid body displacement, that is any isometry, preserves distances but in general changes abolute positions.

(image credits)
